# What is the best way to launch a process when the Internet connection goes up/down?

Tags: networking

What is the best way to automatically launch a process when the Internet connection goes up/down?

Answer (score 3):

The old-school way is to put a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` and `if-down.d`.  I'm not sure if that still works with NetworkManager or not.  There should be scripts in there that you can copy to get started.